# Is It possible to set the background of a property THROUGH a variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm interested in changing the background color of an element by accessing the background color once with a variable and then to I'd like to set it to another background color, also, through the variable.

This is the relevant part in my 'before' code (Which works fine) :

```js
function switchToGreen(index) {
  var allGreen = true;
  var t = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var t_cur = t[index];

  if (t_cur.style.backgroundColor == "white") {
    t_cur.innerHTML = "1";
    t_cur.style.backgroundColor = "lightGreen";
  } else {
    t_cur.innerHTML = "- 1";
    t_cur.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Though this code might work fine, I feel that it can be much neater if I could write this "t_cur.style.backgroundColor" once when initializing the variable and so I've tried to change my code to (I've marked with ** the relevant changes) :

```js
var allGreen = true;
var t = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
/* ** */ var t_bgClr = t_cur.style.backgroundColor; /* ** */
var t_cur = t[index];

if (/* ** */ t_bgClr == "white" /* ** */) {
  t_cur.innerHTML = "1";
  /* ** */ t_bgClr = "lightGreen"; /* ** */
}
```

What's so strange to me and I would appreciate an explanation as to why it happens is that when I do that, it does execute this part :

#### t_cur.innerHTML = "1"

Which tells me it does enter my 'if' statement, as well as it's true that t_bgClr is white, yet, it won't execute this part :

#### t_bgClr = "lightGreen"

as it should.

Is it not possible to set background color of a property through a variable? 
 Is there a difference in which to how I should use a variable when wanting to get or set a property background?

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Disclaimer worth mentioning since in my other post I've got corrected for my English - *English isn't my primary language*, and yet I try my best to check my grammar and to write my questions as properly as I can.
If there is anything you feel that isn't quite explanatory or unclear, let me know, I would be happy to learn and improve.

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can very well do something like this:

```
       var shortened = t_cur.style; 
       if (shortened.backgroundColor == "white") {
           t_cur.innerHTML = "1";
           shortened.backgroundColor = "lightGreen";
       }

      else {
          t_cur.innerHTML = "- 1";
          shortened.backgroundColor = "white";
       }
       ....
```

However, below will not work:

```
var shortened = t_cur.style.backgroundColor;
       if (shortened == "white") {
           t_cur.innerHTML = "1";
           shortened = "lightGreen";
       }
```

the reason is, here `shortened` is just the value of `t_cur.style.backgroundColor`, you can change this value in this *variable* however you want, it won't affect the DOM.

let's mimic this with `object` and `string`.

```
   var a = "foo", b = a; 
   b = "bar" // if you do this 'a' will still remain "foo";

   var x = {"foo": "bar"}
   var y = x;
   y.foo= "changed bar";
   console.log(x.foo) //it will be "changed bar" now
```

This is what's happening in your case as well. `t_cur.style` is an object while `t_cur.style.backgroundColor` is just a `string`. if you keep changing the value of the string, original string will not be affected. On the other hand if you change a property of an object that is derived from another object, it will affect the original object.

```js
 var t = document.getElementById("myId");

 var common = t.style;
 common.background = 'red';
 
 common.background = 'blue';
```

```html
<div id ="myId" style="width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid">
sfsf
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the folowing code,

```
t_bgClr = t_cur.style.backgroundColor;
```

t_bgClr stores string (e.g. white"). That is why you are able to t_bgClr stores string (e.g. white"). That is if(t_bgClr == "white") ... condition works. t_bgClr **deos not** contain a reference to the backgroundColor property of t_cur.style.

So t_bgClr = "lightGreen" changes the string value of the variable, not the backgroundColor property. if you want to shorten the code, you code try something like this:

```
var allGreen = true;
var t = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var t_bgClr = t_cur.style.backgroundColor;
var t_curStyle = t_cur.style;
var t_cur = t[index];    
if (t_bgClr == "white"**) {
    t_cur.innerHTML = "1";
    t_bgClr = "lightGreen";
    t_curStyle.backgroundColor=t_bgClr;
}
```